# can't seem to update a text view in surface overlay

Tags: android, android-service, android-windowmanager

I have created a Service as seen below.. The service creates a system overlay with a text view that is displaying the time.  I have an inlined timer class that is suppose to update the textView with the current time by calling a public method of the Service class.. i know its firing the method and passing the new time via the log i placed in the method but it only seems to change the text in the text view the first time.  I assume this has something to do with the surface overlay not redrawing.. anyone have any ideas how i can fix this or if it is even possible:

```
public class cusNavOverrideService extends Service {

Timer timer;
WindowManager.LayoutParams handleParams;
WindowManager.LayoutParams clockParams;
View screenBlock;
View disableStatusBar;
WindowManager winMgr;
TextView clock;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    winMgr = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE); 
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    disableStatusBar = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());


     handleParams =  new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             50,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
             PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);



     handleParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
     handleParams.y = 752;

     clockParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             50,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
             PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);


     clockParams.y = 752;

    disableStatusBar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cust_bar);

     winMgr.addView(disableStatusBar, handleParams);


     Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Futura Bold.otf");
     clock = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
     clock.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     clock.setTextSize(30.0f);
     clock.setWidth(50);
     clock.setTypeface(tf);
     clock.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
     clock.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
     clock.setPadding(0, 5, 50, 0);


     winMgr.addView(clock, clockParams);


     timer = new Timer();
     uiCheckTask tTask = new uiCheckTask();
     tTask.setService(this);
     timer.schedule(tTask, 100, 200);

     return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
public void updateClock(String newTime){

    Log.v("updateClock", "(((((((((((((((((((("+newTime+")))))))))))))))))");
    clock.setText(newTime);



}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // We don't provide binding, so return null
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    timer.cancel();
    winMgr.removeView(disableStatusBar);
  //Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}


class uiCheckTask extends TimerTask {

    cusNavOverrideService myService;
    String newTime;
    String tempTime;
    Time cTime; 
    String displayTime;

   public void setService(cusNavOverrideService service){
       myService = service;
       cTime= new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
   }


    public void run() {


        try {

            cTime.setToNow();
            displayTime = cTime.format("%I:%M%P");

            if(displayTime.startsWith("0")){
               //displayTime ="CHUCK";
                newTime = displayTime.substring(1);
            }else{
                newTime = displayTime;
            }
            myService.updateClock(newTime);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.v("WINDOW CHANGE", "exemption:"+ex);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Timer runs in its own Thread and only the UI Thread is allowed to update visible stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was to create a handler instead of a timerTask

Comment: it is one possible solution, yes

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with my view(s) not disappearing and reappearing. It has to do something with the fact that you (we) added a view using WindowManager.addView(...). Everything is working it is just not updating. Maybe an invalidate?